# controller's function name and view file (.ctp) name should be same in cake php?

Tags: cakephp

if i used this it's working. but if i rename function name, it shows
error

IN view file:

`echo $this->Html->link(
    '<span>Page 1</span>',
    array('action' => 'ra'),
    array('escape' => false));`

In controller:

```
public function ra()
    {
    $this->render('ra');    
    }
```

Comment: Please show a little effort when asking questions. Make your code readable, explain exactly what the problem is, what you have tried to solve it, and also mention your exact CakePHP version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View template files are named after the controller functions they display, in an underscored form. The getReady() function of the PeopleController class will look for a view template in `/app/views/people/get_ready.ctp.`

The basic pattern is `/app/views/controller/underscored_function_name.ctp.`

By naming the pieces of your application using CakePHP conventions, you gain functionality without the hassle and maintenance tethers of configuration. Here’s a final example that ties the conventions

Database table: “people”
Model class: “Person”, found at `/app/models/person.php`
Controller class: “PeopleController”, found at

```
/app/controllers/people_controller.php
View template, found at /app/views/people/index.ctp
```

Read : **[View Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Basic-Principles-of-CakePHP/CakePHP-Conventions.html#view-conventions)**

Also Read : **[CakePHP Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Basic-Principles-of-CakePHP/CakePHP-Conventions.html#cakephp-conventions)**

Answer (score 1):

By convention, the view file must be the same as the method (action) name.

If you want to change the *appearance* of a URL, you should use [routes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html), rather than rename your methods/views.

If you wish to render a different `.ctp` file for a given action, then you can override the default behaviour like so:

```
public function ra() {
    $this->render('my_other_view'); 
}
```

The `action` specified in the URL must always exist to avoid an error (but routing lets you use alternative "names" for the action and maps them to the appropriate controller method).